# How to define an argument of NTuple with a specific length in Julia

Tags: function, types, julia

As mentioned I would like to have an argument in the function that is a `NTuple` but its length is relevant to a former argument, such as `x` here:

```
f(fleet::Vector{Int64}, x::NTuple{N, Int64} where N=length(fleet)} #pseudo code
```

How can I define the function?

Comment: This is not possible, since the lengths of vectors are not encoded in the type domain. The first input must also be a tuple, then you can match their lengths.

Comment: StaticArrays.jl can also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `Vector`s do not have length as part of their type information, tuples and static arrays do. Hence you can either do:

```
f(fleet::NTuple{N, Float64}, x::NTuple{N, Int64}) where N
```

or `using StaticArrays`

```
f(fleet::SVector{N, Float64}, x::NTuple{N, Int64}) where N
```

in both cases you are enforcing the same lenght `N` via the type information.