# Dispatch cannot match a method when defining the dimension type of `NTuple()`

Tags: julia

I'm trying to figure out how to define the dimensions of a tuple when calling a `function` or contructing a `struct` when the arguments contain a `NTuple` type.
If I leave the dimension variable (which defines the size of the `Tuple`) "free" (<:Any), everything works and it is of an `Integer` subtype. If I try to define it as any `Integer` subtype I get an error that the dispatch cannot match a method.

Here's a concrete example:
Say that I want to generate several variables of a `vector` or `tuple` type and force the same dimensions `nDims`. Here is a "stupified" version where all other things are simplified:

```
struct GridStruct{nDims}
    NumCells :: NTuple{nDims, Integer}
    DomainLength :: NTuple{nDims, AbstractFloat}
    x :: Base.AbstractVecOrTuple{AbstractFloat}
    y :: Base.AbstractVecOrTuple{AbstractFloat}
    z :: Base.AbstractVecOrTuple{AbstractFloat}

    function GridStruct(DomainLength::NTuple{nDims,AbstractFloat},NumCells::NTuple{nDims,Integer}) where nDims<:Integer
        
        x=GenerateCoordinate(NumCells[1], DomainLength[1]);
        y=GenerateCoordinate(NumCells[2], DomainLength[2]);
        z=GenerateCoordinate(NumCells[3], DomainLength[3]);

        new{nDims}(NumCells,DomainLength,xf,xc,yf,yc,zf,zc)
    end
 end
```

You can set `GenerateCoordinate` to be whatever you want, like a simple uniform linear distribution:

```
GenerateCoordinate(N::Integer,L::AbstractFloat)=Base._linspace(0.0,L,N)
```

My question revolves around the definition of `nDims` here: when I let it be "free" (so not defined", everything works fine and when I test the type of `nDims` - it is indeed a subtype of `Integer` (`Int64` on my system) and has the expected value of 3 (as this is a 3D space).
If I try to define `nDims` in any way, say `nDims<:Integer`, I get an error that there is "no method" which matches:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching Main.GridGenModule.GridStruct(::Tuple{Float64, Float64, Float64}, ::Tuple{Int64, Int64, Int64})
```

If I use `nDims<:Any`, it obiously works - but there is nothing between `::Number` and `::Any` that I know of... And from what I can see, it is not any other type either.
I'm trying to understand why defining `nDims` (i.e. `nDims<:Integer`) causes issues.

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75816960/how-to-define-an-argument-of-ntuple-with-a-specific-length-in-julia) that is related but there was no explanation or content regarding the issue I'm asking about. I know how to get it to work, this is more for me to understand the "mechanics" of this.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nDims <: Integer` cannot work. The `<:` relation is for types, not for values, so `Int <: Integer` is `true`, but `3 <: Integer` is `false`. Hypothetically, you could have used `nDims isa Integer`, but that is not valid syntax for type signatures, so you are stuck with leaving `nDims` unrestricted. This is a common idiom in Julia.

Aside from this, your struct definition is full of abstractly typed fields. For the sake of performance, I suggest you either make them concrete or parametric.

Furthermore, I would question the struct design. Do you really need `NumCells` and `DomainLength` as part of the struct? Those values can trivially be read dynamically at O(1) cost.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Does that imply though that there could be an implementation where Val{nDims} is then used in the `NTuple`? 
Regarding the implementation - this is a "stupified version" to represent the problem, not the actual implementation and there is a lot of content missing there, so I'm not surprised it may look a bit silly. 
Finally, regarding the abstract types: I'm somewhat new to Julia, but to my understanding, when running the compilation will use the concrete type from the actual inputs and "trickle it down" - is this incorrect?

Comment: Regarding the point about the AbstractFloat... I think I just realized what you meant. If I got this right, you are referring to the use of ::AbstractFloat rather than a ::T where T<:AbstractFloat? 
If that is the case, this was done when truncating the complex function into a simple dumbed-down version here. The actual function uses T<:AbstractFloat.

Comment: There isn't any point in using `Val{nDims}` in the tuple, `NTuple{nDims, Int}` is correct. As for using abstract type annotations, that does work for function signatures, but _not_ for struct definitions, they must be concrete or parametric.

Answer (score 1):

The `new` constructor should be:

```
new{nDims}(NumCells,DomainLength,x,y,z)
```

note that I removed typeof(nDims) inf favour of just `nDims` as this is the parametric type you want to have.

After that it works:

```
julia> GridStruct((1.,2.,3.),(4,5,6))
GridStruct{3}((4, 5, 6), (1.0, 2.0, 3.0), 0.0:0.3333333333333333:1.0, 0.0:0.5:2.0, 0.0:0.6:3.0)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, but I think you misunderstood the question. 1. The typeof() was a copy-paste mistake since in the original version there were a few more types there - I edited in the question. 2. The question is why doesn't this (corrected) run with **nDims<:Integer** or anything except nDims<:Any (also added in question for complete clarification)?